# Android parsing the JSON data

Tags: android, json

Guys can anyone help me to parse the below JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "oneMethod": {
            "NewData": {
                "Table": {
                    "Column1": "1",
                    "Column2": "2",
                    "Column3": "3",
                    "Column4": "4",
                    "Column5": "5",
                    "Column6": "6"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I am using this:

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("Table");
id = sys.getString("Column1");
id2 = sys.getString("Column1");
id3 = sys.getString("Column1");
id4 = sys.getString("Column1");
id5 = sys.getString("Column1");
id6 = sys.getString("Column1");
```

But it's saying

> JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Do you want us to code for you !!!

Comment: If you tried it already then share your code we could help you.

Comment: Please read following documentation and code it yourself. : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html.

Comment: I think this might help. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: You would not have attracted so many downvotes if you had posted code earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
  [                                        //JSONArray Jarray
    {                                      //JSONObject Jobject
        "someMethod": {                    //JSONObject object_someMethod
            "NewDataSet": {                //JSONObject object_NewDataSet
                "Table": {                 //JSONObject object_Table
                    "Column1": "1",
                    "Column2": "2",
                    "Column3": "3",
                    "Column4": "4",
                    "Column5": "5",
                    "Column6": "6"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**Code:**

```
JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject Jobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject object_someMethod = Jobject.getJSONObject("someMethod");
JSONObject object_NewDataSet = object_someMethod.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");
JSONObject object_Table = object_NewDataSet.getJSONObject("Table");

Log.v("Column1",""+object_Table.getString("Column1"));
Log.v("Column2",""+object_Table.getString("Column2"));
Log.v("Column3",""+object_Table.getString("Column3"));
Log.v("Column4",""+object_Table.getString("Column4"));
Log.v("Column5",""+object_Table.getString("Column5"));
Log.v("Column6",""+object_Table.getString("Column6"));
```

Comment: @downvoter Can you tell me reason.

Comment: Yes, @downvoter please add comment. its also helps to improve post... I think this is correct but why downvoted..... +1..

Comment: @Hariharan: Hello, someone(moderator) recently delete my one answer with 3 upvote. can you please tell why this is happening..??

Comment: @BlackTiger Hi, Me also don't no about that.

Comment: thanks for reply... why someone do this i can't understand..

Answer (score 2):

```
[  // json array node
    {  // json object node 
        "someMethod": { // json object somemethod 
            "NewDataSet": {  //json object NewDataSet 
                "Table": {    //json object Table
                    "Column1": "1",
                    "Column2": "2",
                    "Column3": "3",
                    "Column4": "4",
                    "Column5": "5",
                    "Column6": "6"
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ]
```

Look at the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

And

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

To parse

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("your json string");
// at the top you have a json array node
JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.get(0);
// then you have a json object. Use the index and then cast to JSONObject
JSONObject jb1 = (JSONObject) jb.getJSONObject("someMethod");
JSONObject jb2 = (JSONObject)jb1.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");
JSONObject jb3 = (JSONObject)jb2.getJSONObject("Table");
String col1 = jb3.getString("Column1");
String col2 = jb3.getString("Column2");
String col3 = jb3.getString("Column3"); 
String col4 = jb3.getString("Column4");
String col5 = jb3.getString("Column5");
String col6 = jb3.getString("Column6");
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at `JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(jsonStr);` as you are getting array while you are using object which is causing a problem!!

always remember

**[ means array**

**{ means object**

so have a look on following code

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)ja.get(0);
JSONObject jo1 = jo.getJSONObject("someMethod");
JSONObject jo2 = jo1.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");
JSONObject jo3 = jo2.getJSONObject("Table");
String column1 = jo3.getString("Column1");
String column2 = jo3.getString("Column2");
String column3 = jo3.getString("Column3"); 
String column4 = jo3.getString("Column4");
String column5 = jo3.getString("Column5");
String column6 = jo3.getString("Column6");
```